# Do loop until with two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a list of ISO-codes (from A2 till A138)
De cell A2 is selected.
In the vba code I ask to open a template run the auto open macro (get data - save as and close this file)
and then in the initial file I want to delete row 2 and repeat the actions until we are at the end of the list.
But the vba stops when the template did the save as and close the file.
What do I have to do to continue the vba in the initial file ?
Thanks for helping !

this is the VBA in the initial file :

```
Sub Scorecalculation2()

Dim ThisWkbkNm As String
ThisWkbkNm = ActiveWorkbook.Name

' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
Range("A2").Select
' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

ChDir "M:\RM\Country Risk\Data\MacroFiches\CRAM templates and critical values"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"M:\RM\Country Risk\Data\MacroFiches\CRAM templates and critical values\RISK_score_OECD - CRAM_PROTOTYPEtest.xlsm" _
, UpdateLinks:=3

Workbooks(ThisWkbkNm).Activate
Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
Loop
End Sub
```

I created two vba procedures

- one for opening the template - run the auto open - save as and close the file
- one for deleting the row 2
  and run them each time manually....

Comment: "...when the template did the save as and close the file..." Where are you saving and closing the file in the sample code you provided? Side note, you should [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) (and Activate) in your code

Comment: the code to save and close the file is in the second file

Comment: It's not clear why you open the same xlsm file over and over?  It seems likely you'd be better off structuring this differently.

Comment: because thats the template and each time new data will filled in. It depends on the iso code.